# cannot upgrade to orchard 1.8

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms-1.8

I'm moving my old website from orchard 1.5 to 1.8. I have done in several steps moving 1.5->1.6.1, 1.6.1-> 1.7.3, 1.7.3 to 1.8 following the documentation:

prepare the new installation, copy app_data, media directories, dirs from themes and modules, and the migrations up to 1.7.2 went fine and the site is running.

At this point I'm following the procedure in the same server (2008 r2), but after I switch the home directory of the site to the 1.8 dir to start the upgrade i obtain the error message:

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /

Am I missing something? the site configuration is the same as 1.7.3, just switching directory

thanks,

luca

Answer (score 0):

found the problem: I have to exclude the dependencies directory in the app_data while copying